# Properly implement Adaptive Card buttons like task/fetch in my Rasa bot

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot, adaptive-cards, rasa

In my rasa bot that runs on MS Teams, I want to create [task modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots?tabs=nodejs), but in order to even start implementing them I need to create proper submit buttons (`Action.Submit`) that get the message back when pressed.

I created a submit button like this :

```
{
"type": "Action.Submit", 
"title": "Submit button",
"data": { "msteams":
  {"type": "task/fetch"}, 
  "task": 
    {"type": "message", "value": "Message text"}}, 
}
```

but when pressed I am getting this on Teams:

[image]

and on rasa's debugging log I am getting this statement:

`2021-11-12 10:14:04 INFO     rasa.core.channels.botframework  - Not received message type`

Any idea on how I could start approaching my problem?

Comment: Errors like these are often related to the domain you're trying to reach (in this case a temporary ngrok one) not being registered in the app's manifest as "valid" domains. Try add it, re-upload the manifest, deploy the app again, and test.

Comment: The domain where rasa is operating from is listed in the validDomains field in the manifest.json. For starters what I would love to debug is why the button isn't registering on the rasa-botframework server side.

Comment: Could you please check if you are configuring the bot properly?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Could you please elaborate more on this? The Bot seems to be working properly (besides my problem described here). Thank you

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft No the issue is still unresolved. Thank you

Comment: @Markos di Mitsas,
Could you please check if your request is coming to Bot Controller, if not it is the issue with your azure bot configuration or messaging endpoint.  Please do verify

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I am running the botframework connector for the rasa bot, and when I push the button a request is visible but it returns the above error:

`2021-11-12 10:14:04 INFO     rasa.core.channels.botframework  - Not received message type`

Comment: @MarkosdiMitsas - We are able to repro this issue and raised a bug for it. We will let you know the updates once we get it from engineering team.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft This is great. Is this issue on github? Could I have a link just to follow the updates? Thank you

Comment: @MarkosdiMitsas -  This bug is raised internally in DevOps so you will not have access on it. We will share the updates once it is fixed.

Comment: @MarkosdiMitsas - We are checking it with engineering team and let you know the updates of bug.